# iron-router with Meteor 0.9 packaging system

Tags: meteor, iron-router

The readme file of iron-router states

> IMPORTANT: Do not install versions 0.9.0 or 0.9.1 from Atmosphere. These versions are intended for the new Meteor packaging system available in Meteor v0.9.0. iron-router 0.9.x was released by mistake to Atmosphere.

Does this mean I can't install iron-router with the new packaging system at all? Do I have to use Meteorite for this?

```
meteor add iron:router
```

... will install the the wrong version from Atmosphere, am I right?

Comment: No, it will install the right version (for Meteor 0.9.0.1). The github pages for iron:router are a bit outdated at the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was for the old packaging system - Atmosphere was the unofficial package system prior to Meteor 0.9. The command you typed will install the newest version of Iron Router to your Meteor 0.9.x app.